# Using Python to read a column from a CSV and based on information in that column write into another csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, keyerror

So I have a CSV (https://uploadfiles.io/o5xm3) with headers (survived, pclass, name, etc). I am trying to use python to read the survived column (0 = died, 1 =yes) and if the person did not survive it will write that person's other information (from the other columns) into another csv file. Here is what I have so far :

```
import csv
with open('titanic-new.csv',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    sortedlist = sorted(spamreader, key=lambda row:(row['name']), reverse=False)

in_file = open('titanic-new.csv', 'r')
out_file = open('Q2_out.txt', 'w')
dict = {}

in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

The first part is me trying to put the names in alphabetical order but I am getting an error:  (keyerror 'name') If someone could help me with that too thanks

Edit:
I downloaded colleague's file and it looks like this (first 3 lines):

```
survived,pclass,name,sex,age,ticket,fare,cabin
0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,A/5 21171,7.25,
1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,PC 17599,71.2833,C85
```

Comment: it might help if you include an example of what the data looks like in the file, including the header. For example is `"name"` the same case and spelling as the header in the csv file

Comment: @xgord I attached the csv file it looks like: http://imgur.com/a/r6wRY (sorry I dont know how to format it here)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to filter the existing CSV to only include non-survivors. This can be done as follows:

```
import csv

with open('titanic-new.csv',newline='') as f_input, open('Q2_out.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Copy over the header (without the first column)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input)[1:])

    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0] == '0':
            csv_output.writerow(row[1:])
```

In this case, the first columns i.e. `row[0]` will be `0`. If this is the case, write the row to the output CSV.

This would give you an output CSV starting as:

```
pclass,name,sex,age,ticket,fare,cabin
3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,A/5 21171,7.25,
3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,373450,8.05,
3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,330877,8.4583,
1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,17463,51.8625,E46
```

The `[1:]` tells it to ignore the first column when writing.

A `DictWriter` could also be used, but for this case, a simple `csv.reader` and `csv.writer` will also suffice.

Comment: I am getting 'IndexError list index out of range' for the 'if row[0] == '0': and it is only doing the first row

Comment: why is it only doing the first row? for me

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: i am using python 3

Comment: `newline=''` is the correct setting for use with a [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader). You will get that problem if you have edited your file and it has a blank line in it, e.g. the last line. To get around that, either remove the blank line from the csv or change the line to `if len(row) and row[0] == '0':`